# Removing data out of output last 3 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT Sys.Name0, Sys.User_Name0, SF.FilePath, SF.Filename, Count(SF.FileName) AS FileCount, Sum(SF.FileSize / 1024 / 1024) AS 'Used Space'
FROM v_R_System Sys
INNER JOIN v_GS_SoftwareFile SF ON Sys.ResourceID = SF.ResourceID
WHERE SF.FilePath LIKE '%' + 'Users' + '%' + '%documents%'
    AND SF.FileSize > 0
GROUP BY Sys.Name0, Sys.User_Name0, SF.Filename, SF.FilePath
HAVING Count(SF.FileName) > 0
ORDER BY Sys.Name0 DESC
```

The problem is, I am getting too much information. I would like to exclude records and not count any where FILENAME is like .exe, .dll, .ico, for example.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Perhaps by using a where clause? Or if you are wanting them not to be counted but still returned you could use conditional aggregation.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Do you want those files included in  SUM() and otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the records excluded you could add this to the where clause:

```
AND RIGHT(FileName,4) NOT IN('.exe', '.dll', '.ico', 'etc.')
```

OR

```
AND Filename Not Like '%.exe' AND Filename Not Like '%.dll' AND Filename Not Like '%.ico' AND etc....
```

Comment: ok, in what location would I put either statement, cause I am not sure how to put an additional 'where' statement

Comment: @dwhite you can only have one WHERE clause per select statement, FYI

Comment: @dwhite I meant that you should add those statements to your existing where clause.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, so I got this to work, now is there a way to only get files that are larger then 1mb?

Comment: here is the whole script
select Sys.Name0, Sys.User_Name0, SF.FilePath, SF.Filename,
Count(SF.FileName) as FileCount, 
 Sum(SF.FileSize/1024/1024) as 'Used Space'
from v_R_System Sys INNER JOIN v_GS_SoftwareFile SF on 
 Sys.ResourceID = SF.ResourceID

Comment: Where SF.FilePath like '%'+'Users'+'%' +'%documents%' 
and SF.FileSize > 1024  
And ( FileName Not Like '%.exe') 
And ( FileName Not Like '%.dll')
And ( FileName Not Like '%.ico')
And ( FileName Not Like '%.ini')
And (FileName Not Like '%.reg')
And (FileName Not Like '%.log')
And (FileName Not Like '%.xml')
And (FileName Not Like '%.msi')
 Group by Sys.Name0, Sys.User_Name0, SF.Filename, SF.FilePath
 
 having Count(SF.FileName) > 0 order by Sys.Name0 Desc

Comment: @dwhite You would need to add something to the where clause related to 'and SF.FileSize > 1mb'

Answer (score 1):

Use this Where clause ( assuming SQL Server )

```
Where SF.FilePath like '%'+'Users'+'%' +'%documents%' 
and SF.FileSize > 0  
And FileName Not Like '%.exe' 
And FileName Not Like '%.dll'
And FileName Not Like '%.ico'
```

This should get you going....

Comment: This did not work, still reports the ini, dll but did drop exe

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add it to your where clause as an extra condition. For your exclusion of the filenames:

```
AND RIGHT(FileName,4) NOT IN('.exe', '.dll', '.ico', 'etc.')
```

To exclude the filesizes greater than 1mb.

```
AND SF.FileSize > 1
```

Full statement:

```
SELECT
    Sys.Name0,
    Sys.User_Name0,
    SF.FilePath,
    SF.Filename,
    Count(SF.FileName) AS FileCount,
    Sum(SF.FileSize / 1024 / 1024) AS 'Used Space'
FROM
    v_R_System Sys
    INNER JOIN v_GS_SoftwareFile SF ON Sys.ResourceID = SF.ResourceID
WHERE
    SF.FilePath LIKE '%' + 'Users' + '%' + '%documents%'
    AND SF.FileSize > 1
    AND RIGHT(FileName,4) NOT IN('.exe', '.dll', '.ico', 'etc.')
GROUP BY Sys.Name0, Sys.User_Name0, SF.Filename, SF.FilePath
HAVING Count(SF.FileName) > 0
ORDER BY Sys.Name0 DESC
```

Comment: Ok, that works great, however, I have another issue, I want to export this to a excel CSV, however it is over 2 Million lines, is there a way to export only 1 million lines at a time?